# Best practices of AngularJS internationalization

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I made my website however it's in French and I want to make it in English too.

My question is if we want a multilingual support **should we use Angular i18n or create 2 views (one french the other english) ?**

What do you advise me?

Thanks

Comment: check angular-translate

Comment: Angular-translate is the best solution available for angular nowadays